# CommandButton Primefaces não chama o método

Tags: java-ee, jsf, primefaces

Meu `commandbutton` não apresenta erro ao ser clicado, porém também não executa o método.

**Código do commandbutton:**

```
p:commandButton action="#{clienteMB.cliente.Salvar}" value="Incluir"/
```

**Código do método:**

```
public void Salvar(){
        System.out.println("Funcionou...);
}
```

Utilizando o apache tomcat funcionou bem, mas no glassfish não apresenta resultado e nem erros. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Realmente Salvar() esta dentro de cliente? ou esta na Classe clienteMB?

Comment: O método realmente está dentro da classe Cliente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando usar `action` ou `actionListener`:

`action` é usado quando você irá realizar ação/nagevação. Seu método precisa retornar uma String com o próximo destino ou retornar null para permanecer na mesma tela.

`actionListener` é usado para alterar componentes ou estado de algum objeto, por exemplo, executar um método e depois atualizar um tabela.

Tente da seguinte maneira:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{clienteMB.cliente.Salvar}" process="@this" value="Incluir"/>
```

Comment: Amigo, dessa forma funcionou perfeitamente. Imensamente grato a ti. Valeu mesmo!!